# is it a good idea to change oom_adj for sshd (for protect sshd from being killed by the OOM Killer)?

Tags: sshd, oom

We have an accident with memory leak on Ceph server. During this OOM Killer came and terminate sshd so we couldn't connect to the server by SSH to diagnose problem.

To prevent this in future we plan to set oom_adj for sshd to -17 or -15. Is it a good idea? What are the risks associated with this?